# How to use the same column to filter and make calculations, such as average, percentage, etc

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have numeric column with scores in my table. I am trying to calculate what percentage of people from that column scored 1. Yet I can seem to figure out how to SELECT the same column twice in order to complete this simple calculation. I'm sure I'm missing something very simple?

```
SELECT scores 
FROM table1
WHERE scores=1 DIV scores;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  100.0 * sum(case when scores = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*) percentage 
FROM table1
```

or since **MySql** evaluates Boolean expressions as `1` for `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE`:

```
SELECT 
  100.0 * sum(scores = 1) / count(*) percentage 
FROM table1
```

or use `avg()`:

```
SELECT 
  100.0 * avg(scores = 1) percentage 
FROM table1
```